# Create a stored procedure which will generate alphanumeric with auto increment

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment

I need to display a label field with system generated value i.e alphanumeric value.So
is it possible to create a stored procedure which will return alphanumeric value, with auto increment value every time that it is executed.
where the alpha value will be constant like "ABC" only the numeric value will be incremented.

For example:

```
1st time => ABC12345
2nd time => ABC12346
```

and so on.

Comment: Which version? WIth the newer noes using a sequence that is trivial (get number from sequence, add prefix, finished).

Comment: Can you please post the code?@TomTom

Comment: 2 options to consider: store the 'alpha' part in a string, and use a normal autoincrement for the number, second, store the entire value as a number but report as alphanumeric.

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server. Which are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

Create `FUNCTION` instead of `Stored Procedure`

```
CREATE FUNCTION USF_GenerateNewID() RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Prefix VARCHAR(3) = 'ABC'
    DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(10)
    SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM <TABLE> ORDER BY ID DESC)

    SET @ID = @Prefix + CAST((CAST(REPLACE(@ID,@Prefix,'') AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10))

    RETURN @ID
END
```

Comment: please tell how to run and test this function....